# jQuery JavaScript overlapping id's

Tags: jquery

I am dragging and dropping elements using jQuery.

I have three div's  div a and div b and div c.

I am dropping div a and div b over div c

But when I drop div a over div c then it says it has been dropped on div c.
How can I find out that div a has been dropped o div b.

Comment: Are you using any javascript framework for that?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest to use jQuery UI [Draggable](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable) and [Droppable](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Droppable). I don't know what you trying to do. But you should split Draggable items to Drappable containers.

This question might help you a bit.

> [How to swap element with jQuery UI
>   draggable and droppable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353241/how-to-swap-element-with-jquery-ui-draggable-and-droppable)